# Upload image icon in the button to the server

Tags: codenameone

I have a button that has an image from the gallery. The image is scaled to the display width and its height is set to half the display width. Now when I upload this image to the server, I send the imagePath which results in sending the orginal image of the gallery. How can I upload the icon of the button? (ie. width = display width and height = half of the display width)

```
getImageButton.addActionListener(f -> {
    Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            try {
                if (evt == null) {
                    return;
                }
                imagePath = (String) evt.getSource();

                Image i = Image.createImage(imagePath);
                Image profileImgg = i.scaledWidth(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth());

                getImageButton.setIcon(profileImgg);
                getImageButton.setPreferredH((Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()/2)-50);

                getImageButton.getParent().revalidate();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
});
```

PS. I want to upload the icon of the button, not the image in the gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaled method produces a new image instance it doesn't impact the file from which you loaded. Also this approach to scaling would distort the image aspect ratio. I would suggest a more sensible scaling strategy such as `fill()`.

You have two options:

- Convert the loaded image to a file object. The easy way is:

  ```
  EncodedImage e = EncodedImage.createFromImage(img, true);
  byte[] theDataOfTheImageFile = e.getImageData();
  ```
- Transform the file directly using the `ImageIO` API

Comment: In the 1st option, how can I upload the file object to the server? I need to get the path of the file.

Comment: No you don't. You can upload a file with a byte array in multipart. You can always save this data using FileSystemStorage but that's redundant if you don't need to.